# Group events close in time into sessions and assign unique session IDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following is a trimmed-down example of my actual code, but it suffices to show the algorithmic problem I'm trying to solve.

Given is a DataFrame with events, each with a user ID and a timestamp.

```scala
val events = Seq(
  ("1001", 1),
  ("1001", 2),
  ("1001", 3),
  ("1001", 5),
  ("1001", 6),
  ("1002", 1),
  ("1002", 3),
).toDF("user_id", "timestamp")

events.orderBy($"user_id", $"timestamp").show
```

```
+-------+---------+
|user_id|timestamp|
+-------+---------+
|   1001|        1|
|   1001|        2|
|   1001|        3|
|   1001|        5|
|   1001|        6|
|   1002|        1|
|   1002|        3|
+-------+---------+
```

My goal is to group events from the same user together into one session if the timestamp gap is not above some threshold (`1` in this example).

In my solution, I determine the given sessions by looking for timestamp gaps and then applying `monotonically_increasing_id`.

```scala
val sessions = {
  events
    .withColumn(
      "timestamp_gap_before",
      $"timestamp" - lag($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.partitionBy($"user_id").orderBy($"timestamp"))
    )
    .withColumn(
      "timestamp_gap_after",
      lead($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.partitionBy($"user_id").orderBy($"timestamp")) - $"timestamp"
    )
    .withColumn(
      "is_session_start",
      $"timestamp_gap_before".isNull || $"timestamp_gap_before" > lit(1)
    )
    .withColumn(
      "is_session_end",
      $"timestamp_gap_after".isNull || $"timestamp_gap_after" > lit(1)
    )
    .filter($"is_session_start" || $"is_session_end")
    .withColumn(
      "min_timestamp",
      least($"timestamp", lead($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.partitionBy($"user_id").orderBy($"timestamp")))
    )
    .withColumn(
      "max_timestamp",
      greatest($"timestamp", lead($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.partitionBy($"user_id").orderBy($"timestamp")))
    )
    .filter($"is_session_start")
    .select(
      $"user_id" as "session_user_id",
      $"min_timestamp" as "session_start_timestamp",
      // Special handling for sessions with only one event.
      when($"is_session_end", $"min_timestamp").otherwise($"max_timestamp") as "session_end_timestamp",
    )
    .orderBy($"user_id", $"session_start_timestamp")
    .withColumn("session_id", monotonically_increasing_id)
}

sessions.orderBy($"session_user_id", $"timestamp").show
```

```
+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|session_user_id|session_start_timestamp|session_end_timestamp| session_id|
+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|           1001|                      1|                    3|          0|
|           1001|                      5|                    6| 8589934592|
|           1002|                      1|                    1|17179869184|
|           1002|                      3|                    3|25769803776|
+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Then, I just need to join these session IDs onto the events:

```scala
val assignedEvents = {
  events
    .join(sessions,
      $"session_user_id" === $"user_id" &&
        $"timestamp" >= $"session_start_timestamp" &&
        $"timestamp" <= $"session_end_timestamp")
    .drop("session_user_id", "session_start_timestamp", "session_end_timestamp")
}


assignedEvents.orderBy($"user_id", $"timestamp").show
```

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
|user_id|timestamp| session_id|
+-------+---------+-----------+
|   1001|        1|          0|
|   1001|        2|          0|
|   1001|        3|          0|
|   1001|        5| 8589934592|
|   1001|        6| 8589934592|
|   1002|        1|17179869184|
|   1002|        3|25769803776|
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

It works, but it feels somewhat clumsy. Especially the definition of `sessions` seems superfluous complex to me.

Does anybody know a simpler solution? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you reduce the complexity a lot by transforming the timestamp data per user to a `KeyValueGroupedDataSet[String, Int]` and then group the sessions based on the `Int` groups without having to care about data frames and columns in the process?

I'm not a Spark expert (this is actually the first thing I'm trying out in Spark) so I'm formulating this as a question. I am not sure if this is reasonable from a performance point of view or if sorting is lost during any transformation step. Anyway, this seemed to work for me to obtain the sessions:

```
val maxDistance = 1
def closeEnough(a: Int, b: Int) = Math.abs(b - a) <= maxDistance

def groupSessions(timestamps: List[Int]) =
    timestamps.drop(1).foldLeft(List(List(timestamps.head))) {
        (acc, e) =>
            if (closeEnough(e, acc.head.head)) (e :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
            else List(e) :: acc
    }

val sessions =
    events
      .groupBy("user_id")
      .as[String, (String, Int)]
      .mapValues(_._2)
      .flatMapGroups((s, ii) =>
          groupSessions(ii.toList.reverse)
             .map(sessionTs => (s, sessionTs.head, sessionTs.last))
      )
      .toDF("session_user_id", "session_start_timestamp", "session_end_timestamp")
      .orderBy($"session_user_id", $"session_start_timestamp")
      .withColumn("session_id", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

I borrowed the `groupSessions()` function from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817742/302793).